# parallelize iterations over pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, joblib

I have a function that I would like to iterate over pandas dataframe by group of indexes.
Simplifying it I have something like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"colA": ["x"]*5+["y"]*5,
                "colB": ["a"]*2+["b"]*2+["c"]*2+["d"]*2+["e"]*2, 
                "colC": range(10)})
def example(df):
    df['colD']=df['colC']*2
    return df
def example_by_group(df, group):
    (n,m) = group
    df_temp = df[df.colA.eq(n) & df.colB.eq(m)]
    df_temp = example(df_temp)
    return df_temp
def my_function(df):
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    for _, group in df[['colA','colB']].drop_duplicates().iterrows():
        temp = example_by_group(df,group)
        result = pd.concat([result,temp])
    return result
my_function(df)
```

My real case is very time consuming so I tried to parallelize like this:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def my_parallel_function(df, n_jobs):
    paral_execute = Parallel(n_jobs)
    parallel_function =  delayed(example_by_group)

    execution_list =(parallel_function(df, group) for _ , group in df[['colA','colB']].drop_duplicates().iterrows())

    result_list = paral_execute(execution_list)
    return pd.concat(result_list)
my_parallel_function(df, 2)
```

However, my parallel function is slower than the basic function.
My dataframe has about ~700k rows divided in ~1400 groups.

For some reason, I'd like to avoid installing other libraries (dask, polars etc.).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I think your code is not well efficient. So try to optimize your sequential code before using multi processing. I don't know about your real code but the following code:

```
for _, group in df[['colA','colB']].drop_duplicates().iterrows():
...
df_temp = df[df.colA.eq(n) & df.colB.eq(m)]
```

is clearly a `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['colA', 'colB'])
```

So you don't need to subset it manually and create 1400 copy of your dataframe. Let Pandas handle groups for you (it's not a view but it's clearly not a full copy).

Another point, why do you return the whole dataframe if you compute only one column? Return a `Series` instead.

Try this simple version with `multiprocessing` module:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

def parallel_function(groupname, subdf):
    print(groupname)
    return subdf['colC'] * 2
    
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    data = pool.starmap(parallel_function, df.groupby(['colA', 'colB']))
df['colD'] = pd.concat(data)
```